# C# get value of dynamically created control

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I have `Label` controls in `Panel` controls that need to be updated. The `Panel` and `Label` controls are dynamically created. Now I need to find a way to get the value of 1 `Label` in a `Panel`.

**C# Code**

```
            // Create Panel
            Panel newpanel = new Panel();
            newpanel.Name = "panel_" + reader.GetValue(0);
            newpanel.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            newpanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            newpanel.Parent = FlowPanel;

            // Create Label
            Label newipaddress = new Label();
            newipaddress.Name = "lbl_ip_add";
            newipaddress.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            newipaddress.Location = new Point(55, 175);
            newipaddress.Parent = newpanel;

-------------

foreach (Panel p in FlowPanel.Controls)
{
    string ip = !!! GET IP FROM LABEL !!!
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    IPAddress pingIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    PingReply pingReply = pingSender.Send(pingIP);

    lbl_ping_1.Text = string.Format("Ping: {0}", pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString());
    if ((int)pingReply.RoundtripTime < 150)
    {
        lbl_ping_1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if ((int)pingReply.RoundtripTime < 200)
    {
        lbl_ping_1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_ping_1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The string ip needs to get the IP from the `Label`. The IP is in string format that will be converted to the IP address as you can see.

How can I get the value of the dynamically created `Label`?

Comment: You could attach the label to the panel's `Tag` property.

Comment: Can there be multiple labels in the panel? Is the problem that you don't know the name of the label control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GUI Tools like labels really shouldn't *hold* the data, it should just *show* the data.  So in your case, it would really be better to hold the label information in a local variable or dictionary.

In either case, you can search your panel's control collection for the label's name (control key):

```
string ip;
if (p.Controls.ContainsKey("ipLabel")) {
  ip = p.Controls["ipLabel"].Text;
}
```

This assumes when you created your label, you named it "ipLabel":

```
Label ipLabel = new Label();
ipLabel.Name = "ipLabel";
```

**Update:**

You also need to add the controls to the container using the `Controls` collection instead of setting the `Parent` of the control.

Example:

```
newpanel.Controls.Add(newipaddress);
```

I would do this with the panel to the flowpanel control as well:

```
FlowPanel.Controls.Add(newpanel);
```

Comment: The label is called: 'lbl_ip_add'. Even though, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I can't find what's going wrong here..

Comment: @Rune The `..ContainsKey("lbl_ip_add")` function would return false if the label did not exist, so you shouldn't be getting an error.  Pay close attention to the fact that I *named* my dynamic label.  If you still can't get it to work, you might have to add more code in your question that shows how you are creating your dynamic label and adding it to the panel.

Comment: @Rune I updated the answer.  I think you need to use `Controls.Add(...)` versus the `Parent = ...` method.

Comment: Changed it to the controls.add, but still same error. I get the error because I removed the if you gave me, to check if it errors and what error i get. I use this to check the result at the moment: "MessageBox.Show(p.Controls["lbl_ip_add"].Text);"

Comment: @Rune Then the problem is somewhere else in your code.  I just test it out and I got a messagebox result.  Make sure you don't have *other* panels in your FlowPanel control that don't have that dynamic label, because your code is expecting that label to be in every panel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will start it from the beginning again so I can try and fix the mistake somehow. I guess this is the correct answer, so i'll put it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if you create the controls dynamically you should do so on every page generation. Best place to do this is in the `PreInit` event. Then you can have events and state just like normal controls in the `OnLoad` event.